# Find a formula relating $\arcsin (x)$ and $\arccos (x)$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, inverse

From the formula $\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-x)=\cos x$, find a formula relating $\arcsin (x)$ and $\arccos (x)$.

I have no idea where to start.

Comment: A possible approach (at least a possible first step): apply this formula to $x$ chosen to be $x=\arccos y$. (also, be careful about the actual definitions of $\arccos$ and $\arcsin$, esp. their range).

Answer (score 6):

$$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $$
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Notice, let $$\cos \theta =x\implies \theta=\cos^{-1}(x)$$

Now, we know that $$\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta\right)=\cos \theta$$
setting $\cos \theta=x$, we get 
$$\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta\right)=x$$ $$\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta=\sin^{-1}(x)$$
setting $\theta=\cos^{-1}(x)$, we get 
$$\frac{\pi}{2}-\cos^{-1}(x)=\sin^{-1}(x)$$
$$\color{red}{\sin^{-1}(x)+\cos^{-1}(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}}$$

Comment: Putting some of this in "spoiler" tags (i.e., hidden bydefault) may be a good idea -- the OP seems to ask for a hint, and this is giving everything away.

Comment: This is not the answer to the problem.