# Find a formula relating $\operatorname{arcsin}(x)$ and $\operatorname{arccos}⁡(x)$

Tags: trigonometry, inverse

> From the formula $\sin\left(\frac{π}{2}−x\right)=\cos x$, find a formula relating $\operatorname{arcsin}(x)$ and $\operatorname{arccos}⁡(x)$.

I have figured out that the domain of $x$ is $[-1;1]$, but I have no idea how to do this. I've tried letting $y=\cos x$ and the only result I've got is $$\operatorname{arccos}(y)+\operatorname{arcsin}(y)=\frac{π}{2}$$
I need a full answer.

Comment: See http://www.enotes.com/homework-help/prove-identity-400063

Comment: I think this is what you want. You have found the formula. $\sin^{-1}x+\cos^{-1}x=\frac\pi2$

Comment: See also the previous post by the same poster: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1458049/find-a-formula-relating-arcsin-x-and-arccos-x?lq=1

Answer (score 2):

For values of $y\in(0,1)$ you can prove this geometrically:

Denote $\arccos y=\alpha$. Then by definition $\cos \alpha=y$. Draw a right triangle $ABC$ with hypotenuse $AB= 1$, side $AC=y$ and the angle $\angle BAC=\alpha$. Then if you denote $\angle ABC=:\beta$, you get $\sin \beta=\frac{AC}{AB}=\frac{y}{1}=y$. So $\arcsin y=\beta$. But obviously $\alpha+\beta=\frac{\pi}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

Your question is like:

In a right angled triangle cos of one acute angle  $ \alpha = x/\sqrt{x^2+y^2}  $ and sine  of the other  acute angle  $ \beta  = y/\sqrt{x^2+y^2}. $ Find relation between $ \alpha,\beta. $

Answer is provided by the direct definition of the trig ratios as : $ \alpha+ \beta = \pi/2. $